# How to animate a collection of elements using react state without clickevent?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

I have a list of collections like so:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo...",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo...",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo...",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo...",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo...",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo...",
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

These collections are full-screen images which I would like to animate them. The problem is that I'm trying to animate them without any click event, (more like a loop) and I want it to be animated indefinitely.

This is what I have so far:

```js
  render() {

    const items = this.state.items.map((item, i) => {
      if (i === this.state.show) {
        return (
            <img src={item} alt="" className="bg" key={i}/>
        )
      } else {
        return null
      }
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="arrow" onClick={this.next}><ArrowLeft/></div>
          <div className="img-container">
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName={this.state.slideDirection}
                transitionEnterTimeout={0}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={0}
            >
              {items}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
          </div>
          <div className="arrow" onClick={this.prev}><ArrowRight/></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```